# Displaying Multisite ID number

Tags: multisite

I'm wondering if there is a way to add in a site ID in some code. Long story short we are connecting sales force to display data on our multipress website.

I am wondering if there is a way to add in the ID to the shortcode so that it will dynamically display and I can make a template as to make changes easier later on. So in the sample below I am looking to make the `Playhouse__c='a0q50000005qQbo'` into something like `Playhouse__c='[site_id]'`

i.e. we are using

```
[sectionsforce o="Playhouse_Prog_Vol_Job__c" filter="Display_on_Websites__c =true and Playhouse__c ='a0q50000005qQbo' and Active__c=true and Ages_Served__c='All Ages'"  n="100" ]

{!Playhouse_Program_Website_Image__c}

{!ProgVol_Job_Name__c}

Description: {!Global_Description__c}
Location Information: {!Location_Program_Description__c}
[/sectionsforce]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shortcode you're using provides a standard format filter for the shortcode attributes, then you could perhaps try something like this.

```
function filter_shortcode_atts_sectionsforce( $out, $pairs, $atts, $shortcode ) {
  // is filter set and it contains our dynamic tag
  if ( isset( $atts['filter'] ) && false !== strpos( 'Playhouse__c=\'site_id\'', $atts['filter']  ) ) {
    // get ID, could use some custom helper function here, if complex logic is required
    $site_id = get_current_blog_id();
    // Simple string replacement to replace dynamic part with real data
    $out['filter'] = str_replace( 'Playhouse__c=\'site_id\'', "Playhouse__c='{$site_id}'", $atts['filter'] );
  }
  return $out;
}
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_sectionsforce', 'filter_shortcode_atts_sectionsforce', 10, 4 );
```

Ot if the shortcode (and its callback) is your own code then use the check above in our callback.

Also, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490175/use-wp-shortcode-as-an-attribute-in-another-shortcode, I think trying to use [site_id] in a paramater has the potential to break the shortcode, because the shortcode parser might freak out from those extra brackets. That's why I didn't include them in my example above.